# Is std::container::size_type guaranteed to be size_t for standard containers with default allocator?

Tags: c++, stl, portability

Like:

- `std::string<T>::size_type`
- `std::list<T>::size_type`
- `std::map<T>::size_type`
- `std::vector<T>::size_type`
- etc.

Both [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) say that they are usually `size_t`, but are they truly, unambiguously *guaranteed* by the standard to be `size_t` unless a custom allocator is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For STL-containers - nope. Table 96 of the standard in [container.requirements.general], which lists container requirements for any container `X`, explains it pretty clear:

[image]

---

However, for `basic_string`, `size_type` is defined as

```
typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type;
```

which in turn will be `size_t` for `std::allocator<..>` as the allocator.

Also, `std::array` uses `size_t` as `size_type`, according to [array.overview]/3.

Answer (score 0):

`size_type` isn't guaranteed to be `size_t`.

But the **[default allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)** `size_type` is, so the default is `size_t`.

From the standard 20.6.9

```
template <class T> class allocator {
public:
typedef size_t size_type;
typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
....
```

The container's size_type is derived from the allocator:

```
typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type size_type;
```

Comment: This is only true for `basic_string`. The clause 23 containers are not guaranteed to use the allocator's `size_type`.