# std::map::size_type for a std::map whose value_type is its own size_type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap, size-type

I have a `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, float>` that is taking up too much memory, and in order to use less memory, I've decided to map the unique strings to integers (e.g., `std::map<std::string, int>`, where each new unique string is mapped to the current `size()` of the map), and use those integer value as pairwise keys to the map, (e.g., `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, float>`).

Instead of `int`, I want to use [std::map::size_type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/size/):

```
using map_index = std::map::size_type;
std::pair<map_index, map_index> key;
```

Of course, this doesn't compile because I need to supply the argument list for the map:

```
vector.cc:14:19: error: invalid use of template-name `std::map' without an argument list
 using map_index = std::map::size_type;
```

And this (in theory) is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
using map_index = std::map<std::string, map_index>::size_type;
```

which gives the following (expected) compiler error:

```
vector.cc:15:41: error: `map_index' was not declared in this scope
 using map_index = std::map<std::string, map_index>::size_type;
```

What is the proper way to get the compiler to infer the correct `value_type` for a `std::map` whose `value_type` is its own `size_type`?

Comment: minor nitpick: I think you have the last sentence the wrong way around. To know what is `size_type` you first need to tell what is the `value_type` not the other way around. Once you know the type of the map, getting its `size_type` is trivial

Comment: @user463035818 The problem seems to be that the `size_type` is a part of `value_type` for the OP.

Comment: You have a circular dependency. Why can't you use `size_t` (which is what `size_type` normally will be anyway)?

Comment: can you explain why you want that? afaik `map::size_type` is just a `typedef` aliasing always the same type anyhow

Comment: I understand that I could use `size_t`, or `unsigned long int`, or even just `int` and ignore type conversion warnings, but what I'm really trying to figure out is how to get `std::map::size_type` for a map that uses the results of its own `std::map::size()` as its values. I'm hoping there is a generic solution that relies on templates.

Comment: `std::map<K, V>::size_type` is **most likely** completely independent of **both** `K` and `V`. If you really care, you can `static_assert(std::is_same_v<Map::size_type, Map::mapped_type>, "Unexpected size_type")`

Comment: Instead of using `std::map<std::string, X>`, would [boost::flyweight](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) be a better solution?

Comment: @felix I'm from the Java world and re-familiarizing myself with C++ after many years, so I've been trying to avoid reliance on boost until I've got a solid grasp on STL and its limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is, generally speaking, impossible.

It's conceivable (though far-fetched) that `std::map<int, long>::size_type` is `int` and `std::map<int, int>::size_type` is `long` (and similarly for other integer types), in which case there is no possible way to satisfy `std::map<int, T>::size_type` being `T`.

Conversely, it could be that `std::map<int, T>::size_type` is defined as `T` for all `T`, in which case there is no unique `T` satisfying your "requirement".

As mentioned by several answers (and your own reference link), in practice it's unlikely to be anything else than `size_t`.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, it just isn't the one I was hoping for. The specific examples you provide illustrate the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

`size_t` should be good enough for such case.

But if you insist, you can do like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>

template <class Key, class Value = size_t, size_t depth = 0, class = void>
struct GetSizeType {
    using type = typename GetSizeType<Key, typename std::map<Key, Value>::size_type, depth + 1>::type;
};

template <class Key, class Value, size_t depth>
struct GetSizeType<Key, Value, depth, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Value, typename std::map<Key, Value>::size_type>>> {
    using type = typename std::map<Key, Value>::size_type;
};

template <class Key, class Value>
struct GetSizeType<Key, Value, 100, void> {};

int main() {
    using X = GetSizeType<int>::type;

    return 0;
}
```

It will run recursively on `GetSizeType`, the recursive call will stop upon

- reaching the recursive call depth limitation (there will be no member `type` in this case), or
- finding a specialization of `std::map` of which the `mapped_type` and `size_type` is identical (the member `type` aliases `size_type`).

Comment: Technical thug approach of the first order - brilliant!

Comment: i dont completely agree with " You will run out of memory before running out of size_t.". Something like `my_map.size() * 2;` is a sensible operation that can overflow long before you run out of memory

Comment: @user463035818 Thanks, I have removed that part. I wrongly simplified the usage.

Comment: @user463035818 - in the context set by the question, there's no arithmetic involved - the result of `size()` is simply being used as an opaque identifier.

Comment: @TobySpeight Correct, specifically, that identifier will always be exactly a value that is returned from `size()`. I won't be performing any modifications to those values prior to storing them in the map.

Comment: @user463035818, I'm saying that the result of `size()` will always be assignable to a `std::size_t` (the map can't grow beyond that range), and the comment about overflow if its multiplied by 2 is irrelevant because that's not what the code does.

Comment: @TobySpeight ... i just misread the question ;) sorry for the confusion

Comment: @vallismortis What do you mean by "more extreme cases"? If you use `std::size_t`, there is no way it won't work where another type would, because that should be able to address even objects of size 1.

Comment: Could you prove the convergence of this algorithm? An implementation could make it circular map<...,size_t>::size_type is int and map<...,int>::size_type is size_t.

Comment: @Oliv You are right. A algorithm should stop. I add a recurse depth limitation on it. Should't have Relied on the compiler's depth checking.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: this solution is pretty dumb. We're just going to solve the equation by repeatedly (typically once) trying to instantiate `std::map` until we find one that has the requested key and its own `size_type` as value.

```
template <class T>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <class K, class V = char>
struct auto_map {
    using map_type = std::map<K, V>;
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same_v<
            typename map_type::mapped_type,
            typename map_type::size_type
        >,
        identity<map_type>,
        auto_map<K, typename map_type::size_type>
    >::type;
};

template <class K>
using auto_map_t = typename auto_map<K>::type;
```

If the metafunction can't find such a map, it will either error out because `type` ends up defined to itself, or break the recursion limit.

Comment: Both recursive solutions shown are cool, but I am unsure why one would use this. It still does not guarantee you will find one that works in a broken environment, as you say, so it is cleaner and faster to compile to simply pick one and assert the condition we actually need, no?

Comment: @Acorn yes. I just needed something to do while I'm doing a full rebuild ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::size_t`. The unsigned integer `std::map::size_type` won't be bigger than `std::size_t` and will, in practice, be the same type.

If you want to be sure, assert it:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    std::size_t,
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t>::size_type
>);
```

Answer (score 2):

All C++ implementations in the wild I have used use the same size type for all maps.

So;

```
using map_size_type = std::map<int, int>::size_type;
using my_map = std::map<std::string, map_size_type>;
static_assert(std::is_same<map_size_type, my_map::size_type);
```

this just forces a compilation error if the (reasonable) assumption fails.

Comment: I'm linking [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26433802/2074605) here because your answer seems relevant to it as well.

Answer (score 1):

But are you sure that the `size_type` of a `std::map` depends from the key/value types?

If so, I don't see a way to get it.

But the `size_type` shouldn't depends from key/value types and usually is `std::size_t`.

I suggest

```
using Index0 = typename std::map<std::string, std::size_t>::size_type;

using mapIndex = typename std::map<std::string, Index0>::size_type;
```

You can check you've gotten the right type with

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<Index0, mapIndex>, "no right type");
```

Comment: The compiler has no way to know that the map's size type is always the same - as far as it's concerned, there could legitimately be a specialization that's different.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, that is exactly what prompted me to ask this question. It is that "usually the same as size_t" clause from the [C++ map documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) that really got me thinking about this.

Comment: @vallismortis - from theoretical point of view, you're right (as far I know). I don't see a way to break the circular dependency but adding `static_assert( std::is_same_v<Index0, mapIndex>, "no right type");` you can check that the selected type is the right one.

Comment: @TobySpeight - you're right (as far I know); but through a `static_assert()` (see my modified answer) we can check if we have gotten the right type.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to break the circular dependency is to use a specific type.  I recommend that you simply make `map_index` be a `std::size_t` - C++ strongly [implies](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements) that a `std::size_t` will be assignable to the `map::size_type`.